# IDEA cannot find package

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, package

I have jdk1.8, scala 2.12 and IDEA community 2021.2.3. I created a package and object as below,

[image: Idea package]

```
package PUBL

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.{Calendar, Date, GregorianCalendar}

object DATE {
  def strDateAdd(strDateInpu: String, intNumbDay: Int): String = {
    val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")
    val datDateInpu: Date = dateFormat.parse(strDateInpu)
    val calendar = new GregorianCalendar

    calendar.setTime(datDateInpu)
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, intNumbDay)
    val datDateOutp: Date = calendar.getTime()
    dateFormat.format(datDateOutp)
  }
}
```

Before I run this in a worksheet.

```
import PUBL.DATE.strDateAdd

println(strDateAdd("20210101",10))
```

The editor does recognize it. After clicking Evaluate Worksheet, I got an error message

```
not found:value PUBL
import PUBL.DATE.strDateAdd
```

None of the packages I created can be found when evaluating a worksheet. Any idea what to check?

Comment: Is the object you created a package object or does it reside in a file with an individual name? Because importing package objects can be a bit janky especially with IntelliJ.

Comment: @Aarkon, I created a package object with IDEA. See the picture I just posted

Answer (score 0):

You need to first compile your code using "sbt compile" command so that it generates respective .class files. Further write the code in scala worksheet and evaluate.